# eclipse change default formatter and auto-apply to all projects (including new projects)

Tags: java, eclipse, settings, formatter

I am using Juno. I have been searching, but I can't find an answer. Hopefully, someone can help with the issue I have. 
Every time I create a new project, I need to go to `project > properties` to enable the custom (company) formatter. I even set this formatter in the global preference, but it still doesn't auto-apply to all existing/new projects. It seems like I must enable in project level. I would like to know if there are any options that I don't need to do this repetitive task. If newer eclipse version doesn't have this issue, please let me know what version. I will suggest to upgrade.

Comment: Im not extremely familiar with eclipse. This link might help you though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341314/eclipse-default-custom-formatter

Comment: @Remixt thanks! I read that but I can only find .settings for the existing project. I don't know how to make it global.

Comment: I'll keep looking. Sorry it didn't help.

Comment: @Remixt thanks. when i tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341314/eclipse-default-custom-formatter, then I created a new project: it still requires me to go to project > properties > java code style > formatter to click  "enable project specific settings"